# How to disable SMS in Google's 2-step verification?

Tags: google-account, security, multi-factor-auth

Everytime I log in on a new device or browser I get the SMS text message with the 2nd step digits. It's pretty annoying. I already have the Google Authenticator to calculate my digits and it works great.

How to disable SMS?

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to [Google SMS Auth Config](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/SmsAuthConfig)

   - You'll be prompted for your password even if you're already logged in
2. Click "Remove" Next the phone number

Comment: As a side note. Mine is listed as a "Backup phone number". I might suggest you turn 2-factor authentication completely off and set it up again from scratch. May fix the issue and allow you to keep a "Backup Phone" in place.

Comment: Removing phone number disables 2-step. Having a backup number as the only number lets me keep 2-step?

Comment: **I have removed my number from all pages, but it still doing 2-step by my number**... Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove your primary phone number, which will disable 2-step authentication. Then, using the authenticator app from your phone, re-set up the 2-step authentication without setting a primary phone number. You can then add your phone number as a backup if you wish.